# Alamofire 4: force response to be stored and fetched again from disk cache

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am working with an API that is at times rather slow, but I know that for each unique URL, I'll *always* get the same JSON response. So, perfect to permanently store in the cache, so that at least next time you open the app it's there instantly.

Seemed so easy but it's not working as expected.

```swift
import Alamofire

class ViewModel {
  private let sessionManager: SessionManager

  init() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
    configuration.urlCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 200 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: "cache")
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
    sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
  }

  func getData() {
    print("START!")

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/data/2020.json")!
    let signature = "ABC"
    let request = sessionManager.request(url, headers: ["Signature": signature]).validate()

    let task = request.responseJSON { response in
      print("DONE!")
    }
  }
}
```

It's doing the request and I am getting the "DONE!" response just fine, but it still takes many many seconds, even when I run the `getData` function multiple times. Why is it not immediately returning the cached response?

The response has the `Cache-Control` header with value `private,max-age=31536000`.

I'm using Alamofire 4.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. At least this works. So, I expected that the request would automatically return cached data if it's there, but it seems it doesn't work like that? But I can manually check the contents of the cache...

```swift
class ViewModel {
  private let cache: URLCache
  private let sessionManager: SessionManager

  init() {
    cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 200 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
    configuration.urlCache = cache
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
    sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
  }

  func getData() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/data/2020.json")!

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.addValue(signature, forHTTPHeaderField: "Signature")

    if let data = cache.cachedResponse(for: urlRequest)?.data {
      // Do something with the cached data
    } else { 
      // Do the request
      let request = sessionManager.request(urlRequest).validate()
      let task = request.responseJSON { response in
        print("DONE!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```